# Create a custom scrollbar with spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created with following stylesheet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 14px 14px rgba(80, 75, 75, 0.295);
  border: solid 4px transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 14px 14px #fff;
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* set button(top and bottom of the scrollbar) */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}
```

a custom scrollbar with white track and colored thumb and some spacing through the border and box-shadow settings.
This is looking well when the background of my current section of my dom-element have the same background color than my html background color. As this is not allways the case i want to set the scrollbar background color dynamically.

How can i set the background color from the

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
```

through javascript?

Comment: Why not set transparent/semi-transparent background? Why not use JS plugin for custom scrollbars? Now you only apply for `-webkit-`, what about `-ms-`/`-o-`...?

Comment: A js plugin is a much larger then some lines of css and js.
The transparent background doesnt worked, i tried this with the background´-color of the scrollbar and the html overall and also both together.

webkit is currently just for testcases

Comment: From my experience it's very hard and requires hacks to change display of default browser elements (checkboxes/radiobutton/scrollbars) because what works on one browser will usually not work on another